# mongoengine with gevent, how to close/end connections?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gevent, mongoengine

I'm getting `connection refused because too many open connections: 204` when trying to do `MyApp.objects.get(foo=bar)` in a gevent process. In models.py I have `connect('my_db')`. In my script I do `gevent.monkey.patch_all()`I've seen this question

[pymongo + gevent: throw me a banana and just monkey_patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166998/pymongo-gevent-throw-me-a-banana-and-just-monkey-patchand)

and this issue

https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/issues/272

but I don't understand how to get access to the connection to call `end_request`. I've also tried this patch but it doesn't help me (unless I'm using it wrong)

https://gist.github.com/1184264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the way to do it with mongoengine (assuming you have one, default connection):

mongoengine.connection.get_connection('default').start_request()

mongoengine.connection.get_connection('default').end_request()

Comment: I haven't used mongoengine since I asked this question, but I'm marking it as correct as it sounds about right.

Comment: I just ran into this issue the other day, and found this thread with no clear answer, so figured I'd add the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for posting your answer, that's what SO is all about. All I meant by my comment is that I haven't confirmed that it solves the problem, but I'm marking it as correct anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: This issue was resolved in pymongo earlier this year. Make sure you're using the latest version of pymongo.

Original Answer:

Apparently, you can resolve this issue by using a "proxy class ... that queues requests to workers, they allocate a new PyMongo connections on demand, discard them on connection errors, etc. and call target methods," as described here:

http://groups.google.com/group/gevent/browse_thread/thread/a423d1a15d83f73c

(See the Aug 31, 2011 post by Antonin Amand and the response by Alexey Borzenkov)

P.S. And, in any case, the MongoDB folks are working on resolving the issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-296